# local variable "generatedID" before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

```
def submit():
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE customerID = ?', (generatedID,))
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            if record:
                addwindow.destroy()
                messagebox.showinfo("Customer", "The Record Was Successfully Added To The Database")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "The Record Was Not Added To The Database")

            def randomString(size = 6):
                char = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
                return ''.join(random.choice(char) for i in range(size))
            generatedID = randomString()
```

Hi, what i am trying to do there is that when I add customer details to the database I should get a message saying that it has been added to the database or not. I don't know if this is right. Please can you help me.

Comment: code does not reprocude your problem. Why do you use `generatedID` up TOP and set it DOWN below? What did you do to debug your problem? Please [edit] and prepare a working [mre]. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a function, so don't forget to do `global generatedID` before using it inside your function ;)
Here is an exemple:

```py
myvariable = 1
myfunction():
    myvariable +=1
    print(myvariable)
myfunction()
```

Here there is an error : myvariable referenced before assignement.

So just do:

```py
myvariable = 1
myfunction():
    global myvariable
    myvariable +=1
    print(myvariable)
myfunction()
```

And it works fine ! ;)

Comment: so do i use global under submit function or randomString function

Comment: Under every function where generatedID is used

Comment: when i do that it's generated ID is not defined

Comment: Oh yeah because you can't define a variable inside a function, it has to be already declared out of your function like:
```python
def x():
    var += 1
    print(var)
x()
```

Doesnt work but :

```python
var = 1
def x():
    var += 1
    print(var)
x()
```
Will work